# How sub directive is passing data from his isolated scope to the parent scope directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have created a very nice sub-directive using element-resize directive that calculate the actual size of an element:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('subNode', function () {
        'use strict';
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                displayName: '@',
                nodeWidth: '@'
            },
            controller: ['$scope', '$element', function($scope, $element) {
            }],
            template: '<div element-resize>{{displayName}}-{{elementWidth}}</div>'
    };
});
```

If I run this I can see the 'elementWidth' is updeting great, but I don't understand how my parent directive is now reading the child scope data being created? If someone can give a simple example how they should share data it will be a big help.

Here is **my parent directive which should calculate all sub-directive created width**: Don't understand how to that.

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('nodeCollection', function () {
        'use strict';
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                nodes: '=',
            },
             controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$rootScope', function(scope, $element, $attrs, $rootScope) {
            }],
            template: '<div element-resize><ul><li ng-repeat="node in nodes"><sub-node display-name="{{node.name}}"></sub-node></li></ul></div>'
        };
    }
);
```

The element-resize directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('elementResize', function () {
        'use strict';
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            controller: ['$scope', '$element', function($scope, $element) {

                $scope.getElementDimensions = function () {
                    return { 'h': $element.height(), 'w': $element.width() };
                };

                $scope.$watch($scope.getElementDimensions, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    $scope.elementHeight = newValue.h;
                    $scope.elementWidth = newValue.w;
                }, true);
            }]
        };
    }
);
```

Comment: I am afraid it is not clear what you are asking here. Do you want the parent directive to iterate over all its children which have the `element-resize` directive on them and find the maximum (?) of their `elementWidth` or `elementHeight`?

Comment: yes, exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. The parent should be update on each creation of sub-node and add is elementWidth to a variable on the parent scope. I would like to be able to know on parent scope the max width of all childrens.